# Mongoose - using less than operator for date timestamp in aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a bunch of documents in a collection called posts as shown below with their creation date.

[image]

I'm trying to retrieve the 10 documents whose creation date is less than the date provided using aggregate query below.

```
PostModel.aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            "$and": [{
                    "organisationId": "wHQcDpJaFqpRmeS7chXlh"
                }, {
                    "createdAt": {
                        "$lt": {
                            "$toDate": "2022-12-16T11:30:55.183Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "boards",
            "localField": "boardId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "board"
        }
    }, {
        "$sort": {
            "createdAt": -1
        }
    }, {
        "$limit": 10
    }
]);
```

Query returns empty result set. Following section below seems problematic because when taken out query returns data.

```
{ createdAt: { $lt: { $toDate: pageProps?.cursor } } }
```

There is something wrong with the date timestamp comparison but I couldn't figure it out.

`createdAt` property of the document is `Date` data-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you manipulate the compared value with `$toDate`, one option is to use `$expr`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $and: [
        {organisationId: "wHQcDpJaFqpRmeS7chXlh"},
        {$expr: {$lt: ["$createdAt", {$toDate: "2022-12-16T11:30:55.183Z"}]}}
      ]
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5KQyTioqbdD)

Comment: Using `$expr` resolved the issue. There's currently an index on the `createdAt` property. Does the usage of `$expr` negate the usage of that index?

Comment: As far as I know the index still helps